# object and contour detection in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing and trying to get the contours of the apples in these images. To do so, i use openCV. But i do not get a propper contour detection. I want the algorithm also be able to get contours of other objects. So not limmited to apples (= circles).

[Original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDa2w.jpg)

If i follow the instructions there are 4 steps to be taken.

1. Open the image file
2. Convert the file to grayscale
3. Do some processing (blur, errode, dillitate, you name it)
4. Get the contours

The first point that confuses me is the grayscale conversion.
I did:

```
Mat image;
Mat HSVimage;
Mat Grayimage;

image = imread(imageName, IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

cvtColor(image, HSVimage, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Mat chan[3];
split(HSVimage, chan);


Grayimage = chan[2];
```

First question:
Is this correct choice, or shoud i just read the file in Grayscale or use YUV ?
I only use 1 channel of the HSV, is this correct ?

I tried alot of processing methodes, but there are so many i lost track. The best result i got was when i used a treshold and an adaptiveTreshold.

```
threshold(Grayimage, Grayimage,49, 0, THRESH_TOZERO); 
adaptiveThreshold(Grayimage, Tresholdimage, 256, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 23, 4);
```

The result i get is:
[result after processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOfKg.jpg)

But a find contours does not find a closed object. So i get:

[contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Kqv.jpg)

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(Tresholdimage, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

I tried hough cicles,

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;
HoughCircles(Tresholdimage, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2.0, 70);
```

and i got:

[hough circles ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeX3r.jpg)

So i was a happy man, but as soon is i tried the code on an other picture, i got:
[second picture original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdka3.jpg)
[hough circles wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPx2p.jpg)

I can experiment with the HoughCircles function i see there are alot of posibilities, but i can only detect circles with it, so it is not my first choice.

I am a newbie at this. My questions are:

Is this a correct way or is it better to use technics like blob detection or ML to find the objects in the picture ?

If it is a correct way, what functions should i use to get the better results ?

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Try a [closing operation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#closing) to close your contours

Comment: This is really hard problem for classical approach. When you can't explain to computer how to find some objects, CNN is good choice. Mask-RCNN good point to start.